# Understanding the connection between Superior Spider-Man and Amazing Spider-Man in Spider-Geddon

Tags: marvel, spider-man, continuity

At the start of the *[Spider-Verse/Spider-Geddon Omnibus](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/60617209)*, we follow Superior Spider-Man from *Superior Spider-Man #19* on a trip to the future, linking up with Spider-Man-2099 before starting to collect all the other Spider-Men. One of the Spiders we collect is Amazing Spider-Man from *Amazing Spider-Man #7*, whose introductory bio tells us that the Amazing Spider-Man is Peter Parker after his body was returned to him by the Superior Spider-Man (Otto Octavious) incarnation.

I know the whole premise of the Edge of Spider-Verse and Spider-Geddon collection is smashing together lots of different stories from across the multiverse, but I just wanted to clear up this specific relationship.

Are the Superior Spider-Man and Amazing Spider-Man within the Spider-Geddon storyline, different people in the same body from different points of the same universe timeline? Or is this more like the House of M/Decimation set-up, where both timelines (Peter Returned/Otto Remains) have become their own universe?

Comment: @Raj I'm afraid I'm not hugely confident of the answer. I think I have the omnibus edition. And I'm still in the collecting stage, so I suspect it is the Edge of the Spider verse portion. From your question that means the omnibus will contain two different Superior Spider-men?

Comment: @Raj I think this best illustrates how it is important to finish the book before asking questions.

Comment: No worries, it is confusing that the omnibus is entitled "Spider-Geddon", yet the first half of it is apparently just a different story. Anyways, hope we didn't spoil too much for you

Comment: I think it's unspoiled, more that things might have become clearer if I'd just read onwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spider-Verse](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/321/spider-verse) and [Spider-Geddon](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/1395/spider-geddon-the-complete-event) are two separate story arcs, although your omnibus appears to contain both. The first story was published in 2014, the latter in 2018. In both stories, The Superior Spider-Man has the mind of Otto Octavius. As for what body he's in, that differs by story-line:

- For the former you are correct: The Superior Spider-Man and Amazing Spider-Man within the **Spider-Verse** storyline are different minds in the same body from different points of the same universe timeline.
- For the latter, they are essentially two different people. During the events of [Dead No More: The Clone Conspiracy](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/814/the-clone-conspiracy), Otto placed his consciousness in to a new clone body. This is not Peter's body, although it was created using Peter's DNA. In this new body, Otto also takes on the moniker "Superior Octopus"

[image: Superior Spider-Man]